# Hilux Turbo Driver Board 89878-71080

Tags: turbocharger, hilux, driver

Does anyone know what is the no of the 5V Voltage regulator (T101) on the Driver Board for the Toyota Hilux Turbo Driver unit 89878-71080

Steve

Comment: Photo? or more likely check out an electronic components website.

Comment: And ... which number are you asking about?